# QMediaMetaData.ThumbnailImage returns None in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtmultimedia

I am using pyqt5 and python3 for creating a program. In this program i have a area that i want to fill it with thumbnails of the video files that the user opens into the program. 
This is my code for getting the thumbnails:

```
image = self.mediaPlayer.metaData(QtMultimedia.QMediaMetaData.ThumbnailImage)
self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
self.lblthumbnail.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
```

but the `QtMultimedia.QMediaMetaData.ThumbnailImage` returns NoneType.
What i should i do to get the thumbnails?

note:
self.mediaplayer is a QMediaplayer class object.

Comment: What exactly is `None` in your code sample? `image`? Also, does the video file you're testing this with actually have an embedded thumbnail image?

Comment: @TheCompiler it returns none type object. When i get the the type of the first line of code (image) it says that it is <class 'none type'>. I test 3 different video files and al of them was like this. yes they had thumbail images.